# How to create onclick zoom effect like iphone in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want iphone like onclick zoom effect in this html page using javascript,css,jquery.
Tiles are created using div tag and open diff webpage on clicking on it.

Image screenshot
[image]

Comment: may be try this http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is something like this,just tak a look at [css]

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img